# why visual studio archiving always fails

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-mac, xamarin.droid

I have xamarin Native project and when I try to archive build in visual studio 2017 it fails with below error but when I try to do the same with xamarin studio I'm not facing any of this issues and I can archive succesfully

```
Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2,2): 
Error: Could not load assembly 'MyApp, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile? (MyApp.Droid)
```

How to fix the issue and ideas what's going wrong

Update:

This is a xamarin native project

Comment: have u tried deleting and re-adding Xamarin.Forms package in Android project?

Comment: I am doing xamarin native project

Comment: What is `MyApp` assembly in your project ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its seems you have corrupted assembly this will fix by reinstalling the corrupted SDK and install the updated android tools

Comment: you mean to say I have to uninstall the android SDK and re-install it again

Comment: Can you give some steps please

Comment: this is how you do install visual studio alone do not include the xamarin, after installing the VS download the xamarin installer from the website then install, then manually install the SDK